# I won the (a) lottery, but it is not the (a) lottery in which you get money

Tags: articles

Let's take a sample passage:

> Two days ago I learned that I had won **the** lottery. This is not **the** lottery in which you get a money prize. This lottery is for participation in a particular sporting event.

Why is **the** used in sentence 1? This is the first mention of "lottery". Is this an "I went to *the* movie" type of phrase?

Can we use **a** in sentence 2, resulting in the meaning "this lottery is not **a** lottery in which..."?

In short, would this **a/a** combination look natural:

> Two days ago I learned that I had won **a** lottery. This is not **a** lottery in which you get a money prize. This lottery is for participation in a particular sporting event.

The first excerpt is an adopted quotation from a text written by a native speaker. I found myself unable to explain (to myself) why exactly **the** is used in sentence 1, and to a lesser degree why **the** is used in sentence 2.

Comment: Have you ever hit the jackpot?

Comment: Thank you, @TRomano! I see. I just thought "there are so many different lotteries nowadays". I guess one would be more likely to use **a** in "I won **in** a lottery".

Comment: You could certainly win *a* lottery. That might mean something as unexciting as a basket of stale crackers and some mass production cheese. Or a parking spot at the office. But if you "win *the* lottery", you've won some big money.

Comment: Not your question, but _the lottery is for participation in an event_ not for _THE participation in an event._

Comment: Also note that if you have won _a_ lottery, it was an actual lottery (magnitude unknown, as @TRomano points out).  If you won _the_ lottery it was big money, but it may not have actually been a lottery.  _I won the lottery yesterday when my Great-Aunt Hortense died and left me her entire estate._

Comment: Very valuable comments, thanks all! Thanks, @Adam - sentence fixed. (0:

Comment: @F.E. - interesting, thanks! So we use "money prize" as a mass noun in such contexts.

Comment: @CopperKettle Yeah, I made a little boo-boo on that one. :( -- Perhaps something like: *"This is not **a** lottery in which you get money **prizes**."* Yup, that's what ah meant, that's ma story and I'm sticking to it! -- Or even, *"This is not **a** lottery in which you get **money**."*

Comment: @CopperKettle Oh, I just read your latest. Perhaps consider: *"Two days ago I learned that I had won **the** lottery. This is not **a** lottery in which …"* if the "I" only participated in one lottery, or one kind of lottery -- for that would support use of "the" for the first sentence since the "I" would only be thinking of one (kind of) lottery. But if "I" gambles on a lot of different lotteries, then that would support the use of "a" for the first sentence. imo. :)

Comment: But even if the speaker has only one lottery in mind, he also should be mindful of the listener's unawareness, and use **a** if he believes the listener will have trouble guessing what kind of lottery is being referred to? I'm puzzled. I guess the comprehension by the listener of "the lottery" might slide towards "I got very lucky" if the listener had not been introduced to a particular lottery beforehand or has no implied knowledge.

Comment: If you won a big lottery, one that's in the national news or discussed among your coworkers, you'll probably say, *"I won **the** lottery"*. To you, you know which lottery you're referring to, i.e. the big one, though your listeners or readers might not yet know which one you're talking about. But if you only won a small one, and/or you participate in many lotteries, then you might simply say, "*"I won **a** lottery"*, or if you want to understate your having won. Usually, this is a subjective call, and depends on your ear and what you're trying to convey. I think you basically got it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the U.S., *I won **the** lottery* is usually construed to mean: *I won one of the lotteries run by this state's lottery commission*. That is:

> *I won the lottery*.

is pretty much the same as:

> *I won a state lottery*.

but the definite article works because it's assumed we know which lottery you are talking about.

If we are talking about some other lottery, I would write the articles like this:

> Two days ago I learned that I had won **a** lottery. It was not **the** lottery in which you get a money prize. This lottery was for the participation in a particular sporting event.

Incidentally, the word *raffle* is often used in lieu of *lottery* for non-state-sanctioned lottery events.

Comment: I agree that small-prize events are often called drawings or raffles.  That said, common other uses for "lottery" include the method by which NBA teams are assigned their draft order and the method by which conscription order for non-volunteers to the U.S. armed forces was determined during the Vietnam war.  The school district in my U.S. city holds a "_lottery_" to determine the order for who will receive first dibs on spots in the most popular schools.

Comment: @Adam - Excellent point. The only reason I didn't address those usages in my answer is because we rarely here them used in the context of "I won the lottery." However, thanks for adding that comment for the sake of completeness.

Comment: One might also refer to a different lottery as "the [...] lottery", like "the draft lottery" for the NBA or "green card lottery" for immigration.